# JavaFX updating FilteredList when item field has changed

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have ObservableList and FilteredList which contains attached files with field *state*.
FilteredList set to ListView. I want to when changed the field *state* to State.REMOVED,  has been updated FilteredList.

```
/* class Item */
private final ObservableList<Attached> attaches = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private final FilteredList<Attached> filteredAttaches = attaches.filtered(attached -> attached.getState() != Attached.State.REMOVED);

/* Controller */
listAttached.setItems(item.getAttachesForDisplay());

/* class Attached */
public class Attached {

public static enum State {
    NEW, ATTACHED, REMOVED
}

private State state;
private final String path;
private final String name;

public Attached(State state, String path, String name) {
    this.state = state;
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
}

public State getState() {
    return state;
}

public void changeState(State state) {
    this.state = state;
    // Generate some event for update filtered list? 
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your model class (`Attached`) using the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).

```
public class Attached {

    public static enum State {
        NEW, ATTACHED, REMOVED
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<State> state = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final StringProperty path = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Attached(State state, String path, String name) {
        setState(state);
        setPath(path);
        setName(name);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
        return state ;
    }

    public final State getState() {
        return stateProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setState(State state) {
       stateProperty().set(state);
    }

    public StringProperty pathProperty() {
        return path ;
    }

    public final String getPath() {
        return pathProperty.get();
    }

    public final void setPath(String path) {
        pathProperty().set(path);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

Now create your underlying list with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-), so that it fires update events when the `stateProperty` changes:

```
private final ObservableList<Attached> attaches = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(attached -> new Observable[]{attached.stateProperty()});
private final FilteredList<Attached> filteredAttaches = 
    attaches.filtered(attached -> attached.getState() != Attached.State.REMOVED);
```